# Calling ajax to know credits

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Before one of my users realize an action, I need to know how many credits they have to see if they can do the action or not.

I do this using an ajax call, something like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({url: 'getCredit.php',
  type: 'POST',   
})

.done(function( data) {
    if (data.credit >= 1) { do the action }
});
```

My question is: Can't my users "cheat" changing the var (data.credit) to be always >1 with chrome console, or firebug?

What's the best way to ask for their credit?

EDIT: I have a form, and I want to check the credit when they click the submit button, so the form won't send if they have not enough credit to do it. I think this clarify it a bit.

Thanks.

Comment: The UI should limit user actions merely to avoid displaying an error. It should only guide. The server side application needs to validate user actions against the current credit.

Comment: In other words, you should just let them start the action. Your php code will do the credit checking and if not enough credits, bail out before performing the actual action. No credit checking in jQuery, only messaging about it.

Comment: @RST I would have the same problem, I need a variable (flag) to allow my user perform or don't perform the action, and in all ways I can think, he always can change the var. I could didn't understand your answer completely by the way.

Comment: @JorgeBellido I was assuming you had some login to identify the user and read credits from a database table. So if Joe logs in and sends the form. The php will check Joe's credits (Joe can not touch any of that) and if ok send a go ahead signal in return. Or not okay if needed. But it seems you have an answer already :)

Comment: Yeah, that was what i wanted to do, the problem is that Joe can change the variable, but now is resolved, I will check it twice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to check it again in the server side. From the point of view of UX is good for the user that you check the credit before the submit the form, but anyway you will have to check it again once the form is submitted on the server side. For example, since you're talking about current users:

```
if($current_user->credit>1)
  doAction();
```

Is the same with the form validations, you have to do it in client and server side, never trust the user.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, I have to check for credits before they send the form in client-side for the 95% of users that won't seek for bugs, and check in the server if they really have the credits for the rest 5% of users.

Answer (score 2):

**Never, but never trust the user**

The best way to achieve this would be to display and do the actions always in the server.

Answer (score 1):

in `getCredit.php` you should check `credit` and do `{ do the action }` .You do not need to go back to the client unless you want to change `UI`. It does not matter.

Comment: I can check it in the server and return a true if it has enough credits, but I would have the same problem as I commented to @Popokoko users can change to true the request

Comment: what is your ``action``?

Comment: Does that matter? Sending a form, loading any content, place a bid?

Comment: For each task on the server, you must check users account.like ``session`` in asp.net.Changes in the client's not matter.
When finally you do it on the server.

Comment: You talking about when I have to do it in the server, my problem is that I don't want to allow users to do an action, displaying messages, don't sending the form or whatever.

Comment: Because JavaScript is open source.
You can't take certain measures to manipulate your customers.
You can minify javascript file.It is difficult to understand.
So before calling main method on the server, check user permission.Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'yoururl',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                if (data.isValidCredit) {
                    //do the action
                }
            },
            error: function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //handle error
            }
 });
```

Note: iv'e used @Afonso Matos advice and assumed you could return a boolean verifying the users credits (instead of checking it on the client).

Comment: I would have the same problem again, users can change data.isValidCredit to true and make the action, isn't it?